# How do I change the search field label in Django admin?

Tags: django

In Django admin.py

```
class TableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["name", "description", "category"]
    list_display = ["name", "description", "category"]

admin.site.register(Table, TableAdmin)
```

Here, we can change the list_display, label name by using below code,

```
name.short_description = "Product Name"
```

Now the question is, How do I change the search fields label name?

Answer (score 5):

You can override django admin template's `search_form.html` file.

create a new html file [similar](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/search_form.html) to it, and name it `search_form.html`:

```
{% load i18n static %}
{% if cl.search_fields %}
<div id="toolbar"><form id="changelist-search" method="get">
<div><!-- DIV needed for valid HTML -->
<label for="searchbar"><img src="{% static "admin/img/search.svg" %}" alt="Search" /></label>
<input type="text" size="40" name="{{ search_var }}" value="{{ cl.query }}" id="searchbar" autofocus />
<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'My Search' %}" />
{% if show_result_count %}
    <span class="small quiet">{% blocktrans count counter=cl.result_count %}{{ counter }} result{% plural %}{{ counter }} results{% endblocktrans %} (<a href="?{% if cl.is_popup %}_popup=1{% endif %}">{% if cl.show_full_result_count %}{% blocktrans with full_result_count=cl.full_result_count %}{{ full_result_count }} total{% endblocktrans %}{% else %}{% trans "Show all" %}{% endif %}</a>)</span>
{% endif %}
{% for pair in cl.params.items %}
    {% if pair.0 != search_var %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ pair.0 }}" value="{{ pair.1 }}"/>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
</form></div>
{%endif %}
```

Then put it in your template directory's admin folder like:
`(template directory)>admin>search_form.html`

And it should override the label of search button with text 'My Search'

Comment: this seems to override the template globally. Is it possible to override it just for specific admin model(s)?

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to override it just for specific admin model(s)?** Yes this is possible.

In order to do so you need to create following files.

```
YourApp
   -> templatetags
          -> __init__.py
          -> custom_tags.py
   -> admin_overrides
          -> InclusionAdminNode
```

Now you have to register a custom tag) which renders the Search Form.

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import (
    SEARCH_VAR,
)
from django.template import Library

from ..admin_overrides.InclusionAdminNode import InclusionAdminNode

register = Library()


def search_form(cl):
    """
    Display a search form for searching the list.
    """
    return {
        'cl': cl,
        'show_result_count': cl.result_count != cl.full_result_count,
        'search_var': SEARCH_VAR
    }


@register.tag(name='search_custom_form')
def search_form_tag(parser, token):
    return InclusionAdminNode(parser, token, func=search_form, template_name='custom_search_form.html',
                              takes_context=False)
```

Now, we have to use this tag in our `YourApp/change_list.html`.

```
    {% block search %}{% search_custom_form cl %}{% endblock %}
```

Note: Now still you will see that there is no change in the form. But here is the catch we have to add our custom InclusionAdminNode and change the template path. By default it pick from `admin`.

```
from inspect import getfullargspec

from django.template.library import InclusionNode, parse_bits


class InclusionAdminNode(InclusionNode):
    """
    Template tag that allows its template to be overridden per model, per app,
    or globally.
    """

    def __init__(self, parser, token, func, template_name, takes_context=True):
        self.template_name = template_name
        params, varargs, varkw, defaults, kwonly, kwonly_defaults, _ = getfullargspec(func)
        bits = token.split_contents()
        args, kwargs = parse_bits(
            parser, bits[1:], params, varargs, varkw, defaults, kwonly,
            kwonly_defaults, takes_context, bits[0],
        )
        super().__init__(func, takes_context, args, kwargs, filename=None)

    def render(self, context):
        opts = context['opts']
        app_label = opts.app_label.lower()
        object_name = opts.object_name.lower()
        # Load template for this render call. (Setting self.filename isn't
        # thread-safe.)
        context.render_context[self] = context.template.engine.select_template([
            'YourApp/%s/%s/%s' % (app_label, object_name, self.template_name),
            'YourApp/%s/%s' % (app_label, self.template_name),
            'YourApp/%s' % (self.template_name,),
        ])
        return super().render(context)
```

That's it we are good to go now.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Comment by [user20755888](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20755888/user20755888): one also needs to add to **change_list.html** this: `{% load custom_tags %} `

Comment: Do you suggest to name a file `InclusionAdminNode.py`? By `YourApp/change_list.html` you mean `YourApp/templates/YourApp/change_list.html`? `Now still you will see that there is no change in the form.` There can't be no change in the form since `custom_tags.py` imports from `InclusionAdminNode.py`. Are you suggesting to override `templates/admin/search_form.py` by `templates/YourApp/...`? What is `object_name`? In other words the idea is to override `change_list.html` to make it include different templates, depending on the current model? It was hard to figure out from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the previous solution (of Nitish Kumar) you also need to add to change_list.html:

```
{% load custom_tags %}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33395945)